# Error: "No module named _markerlib" when installing some packages on virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I can't install some packages on virtualenv because of this error.

I tried to install:

```
pip install pyups==0.4.4
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

and they give me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-tLx1oC/distribute/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
        writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
        if require: self.require(env, installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
        from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
    ImportError: No module named _markerlib
```

I tried also to install markerlib with

```
pip install markerlib
```

But the error continues.

Comment: same problem here. Various other posts suggest to upgrade pip but I did that an it didn't help

Comment: @Max I solved using --distribute option

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$ easy_install distribute
```

or build from source works for me

Comment: would there be a significant disadvantage of using easy_install instead of pip install?

Answer (score 24):

I try the following command

```
easy_install distribute
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

which works.

Answer (score 6):

install setuptools:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.2.zip
unzip setuptools-19.2.zip
cd setuptools-19.2
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 5):

Although the virtualenv docs says `--distribute` and `--setuptools` options are now legacy, when I created the environment with :

```
virtualenv myenv --distribute
```

the error was gone.

Comment: I solved it by removing the distribute package first and then some other, completely unrelated package. sorry don't remember which one...

Comment: I solve this problem by manually doing `pip install distribute` before installing the requirements.txt. At some point the --distribute option really was disabled in `virtualenv` and doesn't do anything in the current version (15.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

This sound silly. But It works for me. I am using ubuntu. While Installing virtualenv through apt-get install I faced problems. But I got working with pip install virtualenv.

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv

sudo apt-get purge python-virtualenv

sudo pip install virtualenv
```