# ImportError: No module named _markerlib when trying to install via pip

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

Did somebody experienced the same problem? I tried to run a solution from SO:

```
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

And I got the same result, every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-JC9mq_/distribute/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
        writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
        if require: self.require(env, installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
        from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
    ImportError: No module named _markerlib
```

python 2.7, pip 8.1.2

[EDIT]
The solution of creating a new env. with `virtualenv myenv --distribute` worked for the local environment, but when I try to push to the heroku, it gives me exactly the same error: No module named _markerlib. So, the problem is not just in the local env.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "No module named \_markerlib" when installing some packages on virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780537/error-no-module-named-markerlib-when-installing-some-packages-on-virtualenv)

Comment: Check This Out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780537/error-no-module-named-markerlib-when-installing-some-packages-on-virtualenv

Comment: ok, it worked for the local environment, but when I try to push to the heroku, it gives me exactly the same error: No module named _markerlib. So, the problem is not just in the local env.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way, I think.

```
pip uninstall setuptools
download  https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/0.7.3/ez_setup.py
```

Run that,then

```
pip install %HOME%\Downloads\wheel-0.25.0.tar.gz
pip install  Distribute
```

I did this so this would work

```
pip install django-validated-file
```